A detail in the proof of Killing-Hopf theorem for Euclidean surface.
I am reading the book Geometry of Surfaces by Stillwell. In chapter $2$, he proves the following theorem:
Theorem: (Killing-Hopf)
Each complete, connected Euclidean surface is of the form $\mathbb{R}^2/\Gamma$.
Here is the sketch of his proof:
(1) He constructed the pencil map $p:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S$ for connected complete Euclidean surface, and showed that $p$ is a covering map (onto and local isometry).
(2) Let $\Gamma$ be the group of covering isometries for $p$. Define:
$$\begin{aligned}
    \varphi: S&\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2/\Gamma\\
    pP&\mapsto \Gamma P
  \end{aligned} $$
By a laborious work he showed that $\varphi$ is well-defined. Clearly it is bijective.
Now I cannot see why $\varphi$ is an isometry. (I think we do need $\varphi$ to be an isometry to show that $S$ "is" some quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/\Gamma$, don't we?)
Thanks for your help! (For the unclarified definitions and details, please see chapter 2 of the book, there are too many to list here)
